# Polars upsample/downsample and interpolate only small gaps

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation, python-polars

I have a Timeseries dataset that needs to be interpolated such that any gaps more than 3 minutes are left as null values.

The problem i'm facing is that Polars upsample leads to a lot of nulls even when there is data close to the time period. Here's a snippet of the dataframe.

```
                     utc       gnd_p   gnd_t    app_sza     azimuth         xh2o      xair        xco2      xch4  xco  xch4_s5p
0    2022-06-04 04:49:31  955.081699  293.84  77.009159 -109.292040  4118.807354  0.996515  421.510185  1.878339  0.0       0.0
1    2022-06-04 04:49:46  955.081655  293.84  76.971435 -109.250593  4119.081639  0.996508  421.543444  1.878761  0.0       0.0
```

Here's a Pandas code for the same operation

```
    output = sensor_dataframe.sort_values(by=['utc']) # sort according to time
    output['utc'] = pd.to_datetime(output['utc'])
    # Apply smoothing function for all data columns.
    for column in output.columns[1::]:
        output[column] = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(pd.to_numeric(output[column]), 31, 3)
    print(output)
    output = output.set_index('utc')
    output.index = pd.to_datetime(output.index)
    output = output.resample(sampling_rate).mean()

    sampling_delta = pd.to_timedelta(sampling_rate)
    # The interpolating limit is dependant on the sampling rate.
    interpolating_limit = int(MAX_DELTA_FOR_INTERPOLATION / sampling_delta)

    if interpolating_limit != 0:
        output.interpolate(
            limit=interpolating_limit,
            inplace=True,
            limit_direction='both',
            limit_area='inside',
        )
```

Here's the output in a 10 second sampling rate.

```
                          gnd_p   gnd_t    app_sza     azimuth         xh2o      xair        xco2      xch4  xco  xch4_s5p
utc                                                                                                                       
2022-06-04 04:49:30  955.081699  293.84  77.009159 -109.292040  4118.807354  0.996515  421.510185  1.878339  0.0       0.0
2022-06-04 04:49:40  955.081655  293.84  76.971435 -109.250593  4119.081639  0.996508  421.543444  1.878761  0.0       0.0
```

Here's the same attempt at a Polars version.

```
    df = pl.from_pandas(sensor_dataframe)
    q = df.lazy().with_column(pl.col('utc').str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt='%F %T').cast(pl.Datetime)).select([pl.col('utc'),
                    pl.exclude('utc').map(lambda x: savgol_filter(x.to_numpy(), 31, 3)).explode()])
    df = q.collect()
    df = df.upsample(time_column="utc", every="10s")
```

Here's the output of the above snipper

```
│ 2022-06-04 04:49:31 ┆ 955.081699 ┆ 293.84 ┆ 77.009159 ┆ ... ┆ 421.510185 ┆ 1.878339 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0      │
│ 2022-06-04 04:49:41 ┆ null       ┆ null   ┆ null      ┆ ... ┆ null       ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ null     │
│ 2022-06-04 04:49:51 ┆ null       ┆ null   ┆ null      ┆ ... ┆ null       ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ null     │
```

Polars just spits out a df with a lot of nulls. I would have to interpolate to fill the values but that would mean I interpolate the entire dataset. Polars unfortunately provides no arguments or parameters on interpolate() which leads to the all the series getting interpolated which is not the desired action.

I think the solution should have something to do with masks. Anyone has experience working with Polars and interpoaltion?

Reproducable CODE: https://pastebin.com/gQ1WU4zp
sample csv data: https://0bin.net/paste/3fX2AOM2#uQmEv2KvBK5Xk-2vuWxx2z0QgXlttdnaa78eFt8ra62

Comment: reproducible example please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to download your whole dataset so let's use this as an example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": pl.date_range(
            low=datetime(2023, 2, 1),
            high=datetime(2023, 2, 2),
            interval="1m"),
        'data':list(np.random.choice([None, 1,2,3,4], size=1441))
    }).filter(~pl.col('data').is_null())
```

1. upsample, by definition, doesn't interpolate, it (as you've discovered) just inserts a bunch of nulls to match the periods you want.
2. If you only want to interpolate when the preupsampled gap is 3m or less then make a helper column before the upsample.
3. Use `when` `then` looking at the helper column to interpolate or not interpolate.

   ```
   df \
       .with_columns(
            (pl.col('time')-pl.col('time').shift()<pl.duration(minutes=3)).alias('small_gap')) \
       .upsample(time_column="time", every="10s") \
       .with_columns(pl.col('small_gap').backward_fill()) \
       .with_columns(
           pl.when(pl.col('small_gap')) \
               .then(pl.exclude(['small_gap']).interpolate()) \
               .otherwise(pl.exclude(['small_gap']))) \
       .select(pl.exclude('small_gap'))
   ```